# progress bar width not changing dynamically

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to implement a progress bar somewhat like this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_progressbar_3
 by passing the width size an argument . But the width size is not increasing. What is wrong in my code?

> **component.ts**

```
move(width) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("progress");
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        width++;
        elem.style.width = width + '%';
      }
    }

    onMessage() {
      this.ws.onmessage = (message) => {
      console.log("Got websocket message " + message.data);
        // Decode the JSON
      var data = JSON.parse(message.data);

        // Handle errors
      if (data.error) {
       alert(data.error);
       return;
       }
       let percentage = data.percent;
       $('#myBar1').text(percentage + "%");
       console.log("percentage is:: " + percentage);
       this.move(percentage);
       if (data.action == "complete") {
       console.log("uploaded successfully...")
       }
      };
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way the code from W3 is executed, the width is only applied **after** pressing the button. You should notice if your width is set to something like 50, when you press the button the bar will start loading immediately **from 50%**.

If you want your progress bar to start from a different number before clicking, these 3 lines need to be outside of the function "**move**":

```
var width = 50;
var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
elem.style.width = width + '%';
```

You can put it in another function and set the width to a variable based on an input there.